# How to get the current status of a task running inside of a class

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I have a class that does a lot of things, inside that class I have a function which takes some time to finish.
What's the best way to get the 'status' of what that function is currently doing? Is threading a solution or should I start a process or something else?

What I'm trying to do:

```
import threading
import time

class Work:
    def __init__(self):
        self.status = "created"

    def get_status(self):
        return self.status

    def slowFunction(self):
        self.status = "slowFunction started working"    
        time.sleep(300)
        self.status = "did some work"
        time.sleep(300)
        self.status = "slowFunction finished"
    
    #a lot more things here
    #...    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = Work()
    t = threading.Thread(target=obj.slowFunction())
    t.start()

    while obj.get_status() != "slowFunction finished"
        print obj.get_status()
        time.sleep(5)
```

I wanted the loop to start immediately after starting the thread, it currently waits for the slowFunction to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parentheses when passing `slowFunction` as the thread target.

```
t = threading.Thread(target=obj.slowFunction)
```